# Format date on cakephp 3.0

Tags: date, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to convert the time that cakephp send but I can't do it.
When I try to convert the output gives me the date of `01-01-1970.`

I wrote some echos in different styles to se the output. **Print screenshot**

[image]

**The Page:**

```
<tfoot>
        <tr>
        <?php 
        $data = date('d-m-Y');
        //$data2 = new DateTime($ementas['data_ementa']);
        ?>
            <td class="marcacaobutton button-<?=$ementas['id']?>">
                <?php 
                echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data));
                echo "<br>";
                echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($ementas['data_ementa']));
                echo "<br>";
                echo $ementas['data_ementa'];
                echo "<br>";
                    if(date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data)) > date('d-m-Y',strtotime($ementas['data_ementa'])) && $query['status']=='desmarcada')
                    {
                        echo '1';
                        //echo "<td>".$this->Html->link(__('Bloquear'),'/admin/users/bloquear/'.$user['id'],['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'])."</td>";
                    }
                    else if(date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data)) > date('d-m-Y',strtotime($ementas['data_ementa'])) && $query['status']=='marcada')
                    {
                        echo '2';
                    }
                    else if(date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data)) < date('d-m-Y',strtotime($ementas['data_ementa'])) && $query['status']=='desmarcada')
                    {
                        echo '3<button type="button" class="marcar" id="marcar-'.$ementas['id'].'" >Marcar</button>';
                        //echo "<td>".$this->Html->link(__('Bloquear'),'/admin/users/bloquear/'.$user['id'],['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'])."</td>";
                    }
                    else if(date('d-m-Y',strtotime($data)) < date('d-m-Y',strtotime($ementas['data_ementa'])) && $query['status']=='marcada')
                    {
                        echo '4<button type="button" class="desmarcar" id="desmarcar-'.$ementas['id'].'">Desmarcar</button>';
                        //echo "<td>".$this->Html->link(__('Ativar'),'/admin/users/ativar/'.$user['id'],['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm'])."</td>";
                    }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function marcar($id)
{
    $this->loadModel('Refeicoes');
    $id_user = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id');
    $ementa = $this->Ementas->get($id);
    //die(debug($ementa));
    $id_ementa = $ementa->id;
    //  die(debug($id_ementa));

    $query = $this->Refeicoes->find('all', [
        'conditions' => ['Refeicoes.user_id LIKE' => $id_user, 'Refeicoes.ementa_id LIKE' => $id_ementa]
    ]);
    $number = $query->count();
    //die(debug($number));
    $date =  new Time();
    if ($number == 0) {

        $marc_refeicao = $this->Refeicoes->newEntity();
        $marc_refeicao = $this->Refeicoes->patchEntity($marc_refeicao, array('user_id' => $id_user, 'data' => $date, 'status' => 'desmarcada'));
        $marc_refeicao->ementa_id = $id_ementa;
        //die(debug($marc_refeicao));
        $this->Refeicoes->save($marc_refeicao);
    }

    $ementas = $ementa; 
    $query1 = $this->Refeicoes->get($id);
    //die(debug($ementas));   
    $this->set('ementas',$ementas); 
    $this->set('query',$query1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your locale is causing the date object to format output in a way that strtotime doesn't like as input. Any particular reason you're using strtotime everywhere instead of just letting the data objects do their thing?

```
<?php
echo $data->format('d-m-Y');
echo "<br>";
echo $ementas['data_ementa']->format('d-m-Y');
echo "<br>";
echo $ementas['data_ementa'];
echo "<br>";
if($data > $ementas['data_ementa'] && $query['status']=='desmarcada')
{
    echo '1';
}
else if($data > $ementas['data_ementa'] && $query['status']=='marcada')
{
    echo '2';
}
else if($data < $ementas['data_ementa'] && $query['status']=='desmarcada')
{
    echo '3<button type="button" class="marcar" id="marcar-'.$ementas['id'].'" >Marcar</button>';
}
else if($data < $ementas['data_ementa'] && $query['status']=='marcada')
{
    echo '4<button type="button" class="desmarcar" id="desmarcar-'.$ementas['id'].'">Desmarcar</button>';
}
?>
```

Comment: The database format is like YYYY-mm-dd. And if I do a echo the format that cake will print is like dd/mm/YY, as you can see on the print screen i made. The first echo is today. The second is the formated date from the database. The third is the echo of the date from the database. I used strtotime to try to format the data.

Comment: Can it be because of the way that I send the data from the controller to the view?

Comment: When the date is read from the database, Cake should convert it into an object, which can do formatting, comparison, etc. without the need for strtotime. If you `pr($ementas['data_ementa']);` you should see that as an object rather than a string, and my code above should show how you can use it for your purposes. If `pr` shows it as a string, then the problem is elsewhere, perhaps in database setup or your schema (e.g. if you're storing it in a string field instead of a date field).

Comment: Yup, it printed as a object. Cake\I18n\FrozenDate Object
(
    [time] => 2017-06-29T00:00:00+00:00
    [timezone] => UTC
    [fixedNowTime] => 
)

Comment: And have you tried my code changes above to see whether they solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it gave the "Call to a member function format() on string" error

Comment: Solved the problem. I was using "$data = date('d-m-Y');" so i changed it to $data = new DateTime(); Thank you for you time. Very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in to the class Cake\I18n\Time. This comes very handy when dealing with Date/Time, You will still have the same format in the database like "2017-02-28 18:23:02" but if you wan to render "Feb 28, 2017, 6:23 PM" then you can use the I18 "nice()" function in your .ctp file.

Take a look at the documentation on the link bellow...

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html#Cake\I18n\Time::nice

Hope this helps